How do i reduce jupyterlab kernel cache after running pyspark query and downloading it to csv?
I am working in jupyterlab, Python 3.7, PySpark 3 and going to download the result of sql query tab to csv via pyspark and pandas:
import gc
import time

while True:
   sql_query = ‘’’ select * from table ‘’’

   pdf = spark.sql(sql_query).toPandas()

   pdf.to_csv(‘name.csv’, sep=‘;’)
   gc.collect()
   del pdf



   time.sleep(10)


The problem is that if i do this in a while True loop, kernel memory decreases with every lap.
How do i clean memory after downloading to csv?
Btw i ve also tried to use lru_cache and wrap part of code to a function:
import gc
import time
from functools import lru_cache

while True:

   @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
   def func():
      sql_query = ‘’’ select * from table ‘’’
      pdf = spark.sql(sql_query).toPandas()
      return pdf

   func().to_csv(‘name.csv’, sep=‘;’)
   func.cache_clear()

   time.sleep(10)

This helps to decrease the consumption of memory but just a little bit.
